# Python Spyder initializing Hello World Kivi app once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, spyder

Does anyone know why Python's 2.7 Spyder is successfully initializing the 'Hello World' Kivy app just once, i.e. hitting F5 brings the window app, but when I close it and hit F5 again, it says the following error:

```
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] Application will leave
```

However, there is no error when initialized through Anacondas Command Prompt.

Here's the code (same as website):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python / Kivy App running only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042329/python-kivy-app-running-only-once)

Answer (score 8):

Actually the sample program is just a minimum structure for you to try out how the interactive UI can be created in such a simple way.

And the in `TestApp`, it actually didn't implment the `event listerners` to handle the close event. And when you create your actual project, you should always take care of that. Acually if you look at the `logging` carefully, you would notice that the error happens already when you close the `TestApp`, not when you "re-start" you `TestApp`:

```
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
INFO:kivy:[Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
INFO:kivy:[Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
ERROR:kivy:[Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] Application will leave
ERROR:kivy:[Base        ] Application will leave
```

So for your case, the one simple work-around is that you go to `Run->Configure`, in the `Console` panel, instead of you choose to `Execute in current Python or IPython console`, you just choose the second option, which is `Execute in a new dedicated Python console`. In this case, where time your finished the code, the Python will close the current kernel. And whenever you run your code, `Spyder` will automatically create a new dedicated kernel for this particular script.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the webpage: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/kivy-users/yfhH7skAEJA, it gave a solution for fixing this issue, I rewrite the code as below,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
   def build(self):
      return Button(text='Hello World')

def reset():
import kivy.core.window as window
from kivy.base import EventLoop
if not EventLoop.event_listeners:
    from kivy.cache import Cache
    window.Window = window.core_select_lib('window', window.window_impl, True)
    Cache.print_usage()
    for cat in Cache._categories:
        Cache._objects[cat] = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
   reset()
   TestApp().run()
```

The reset() function will clean up the Window's state and run the TestApp() normally.

Answer (score 1):

For use in external system terminal will solve this.
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH8Cq.png)

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zokbe.png)

[Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX5Zk.png)

Comment: I think the answer is correct, but you should use a description with words instead of images to write your answer. That's why (most probably) you got several down votes.