# ArgumentError occurs only after first time running

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy, ipython, spyder

I'm using the kivy package in Spyder's IPython console for the Anaconda navigator. Upon opening Spyder, my code will run without issue if I use runfile(path, wdir=cwd). Yet after closing the popup window, if I try running the file again, I receive the error:

```
   File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
   packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_common.py", line 122, in _closure
        oldAddr = func(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, cast(wndProc, c_void_p).value)

   ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

I'm new to Anaconda and I'm wondering what's going wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

I reinstalled kivy in an administrator conda terminal using

```
conda install -c conda-forge kivy
```

I created a dummy application with very few parts to demonstrate the issue. I've included this code below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class FakeTool(Widget):
    pass


class FakeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return FakeTool()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FakeApp().run()
```

Comment: I wonder if spyder is perhaps reusing the python environment and this is exposing a Kivy bug. Does spyder have any option to use a new python process every time you run the code?

Comment: a bit unrelated, but i strongly recommend pycharm over spyder. can do so many more things and less buggy

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue, found a solution in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057636/9752709

Use the reset() function before launching your app again.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FakeApp().run()
    reset()
    FakeApp().run()
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem while running the MyFirstApp using kivy on Anaconda.

The problem is fixed by running kernel > Restart & Clear Output

Hope this helps. I am pretty sure we can write a command (like reset()) to perform above task before re-execution of command run().