# Kivy not calling on_stop() function after closing app from recent apps list in android

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have created a kivy app for Android. I have implemented on_start(),on_stop(),on_pause(),on_resume() functions as shown below.

```
class Myapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        ....

    on_start(self):
        pass
    on_stop(self):
        print("stopped")
    on_pause(self):
        print("paused")
        return True
    on_resume(self):
        print("resumes")
```

When I minimize the app on_pause() function is called and it's printing paused and on resuming the app on_resume() function is called and its printing resumes. Now the problem is when our app is minimised and then closed from the recent apps list it should call on_stop() function and our app should stop and print stopped. But even after removing the app from recent app list on_stop() is not called and our app is not closed and still it remains in pause state.
If I return False in on_pause() instead of returnig True, whenever I minimize the app or close the app directly on_stop() is called. I want on_pause() to be called when app is minimised and on_stop() to be called when app is removed from recent list.

Now when I close the app from the recent list, it still remains in pause state and on_stop() is not being called.
I want on_stop() to be called when the app is removed from the recent list. How do I achieve this??

Comment: try this solution answered on the stack overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057636/10612772

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this, when your app is removed this way it can be simply killed by Android, there is no guarantee (or I think expectation) of your app getting passed any events.

If it matters to you, you should assume in your `on_pause` that the app will never be resumed.

Comment: When I pause the app, the database should not be disconnected and on resuming the app it should continue with the same connection. But only when the app is cleared from the recent app list I want the database to be disconnected. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to change your requirements, there is nothing unreasonable about the fact that you aren't guaranteed to get the on_stop event and it would be natural to work around that. More generally, you could use a background service to continue running code while your app is paused, but in practice this may have disadvantages (like your users not liking to see a service notification) and possibly even the same problem about not getting stop events if it's killed.