# spyder - REALLY run in a new terminal

Tags: python, kivy, spyder

I'm having the same problem as

[Python Spyder initializing Hello World Kivi app once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289017/python-spyder-initializing-hello-world-kivi-app-once)

or

[Python / Kivy App running only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042329/python-kivy-app-running-only-once)

(Kivy program running exactly once and then failing with

```
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR             ] [Base        ] Application will leave
```

on any following attempt to run.)

Except I'm using Spyder 3.1.3 and Python 3.6.0.

Now according to these topics, the solution that avoids having to manually right-click the ipython console and restart the kernel every single time I want to run the bloody script is to go into the properties and select to "execute in a new dedicated python console".

I did that. It does absolutely nothing, even after restarting spyder.
Neither does "execute in an external system terminal" do anything, spyder will just continue to stubbornly use the ipython/python console currently open.

Leaving it in "execute in current python or ipython console" and selecting "clear all variables before execution" doesn't have any effect either.

So ... how do I get this to work?

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Please open an issue in our issue tracker on Github and post there a simple and reproducible example that generates this error. I'm sorry to say it but we were unaware of this problem.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Apparently can't sign up for Github, right now (don't have an account as I've been using bitbucket), because "something went wrong". Will do as soon as I'm able, thank you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. We'll start to look at this as soon as you post an issue about it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba There's something strange going on ... I have two identical files open. For one, executing in new dedicated python seems to be working, the other will fail with above error. I'll try around a bit longer before opening an issue, just to be sure I'm really reporting what I am reporting.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pytorch and kivy, maybe because of wrong packages it may happen.

```
python -m pip install -U pip

python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

i faced similar problem
change your matplotlib package through above commands. worked for me!